# Why is the range slider step being applied twice?

Tags: javascript, html, slide

I have a range slider that you can move up with the right arrow key on a keyboard or grab and move. The step over `36` is `3` and the step under `36` is `1`. This works perfectly on their own. However, if you were to move the slider manually and then use the `keydown` event, the step is being applied twice to the slider. How can I get the step to always just apply once?

```js
var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('range-slider');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(rangeSlider.value, '1');
  // Update the step size based on the current value of the range slider
  if (rangeSlider.value >= 36) {
    var step = 3;
  } else {
    var step = 1;
  }
  // Set the step size of the range slider to the calculated value
  rangeSlider.setAttribute("step", step);

  if (e.keyCode == 39) { //right
    // Increment the value of the range slider by the step size
    rangeSlider.value = parseInt(rangeSlider.value) + parseInt(step);
    console.log(rangeSlider.value, '2');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type='range' min='0' max='84' value='0' id='range-slider' class='slider' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to cancel the original movement with `e.preventDefault()`

```js
var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('range-slider');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(rangeSlider.value ,'1');
  // Update the step size based on the current value of the range slider
  if (rangeSlider.value >= 36) {
    var step = 3;
  } else {
    var step = 1;
  }
  // Set the step size of the range slider to the calculated value
  rangeSlider.setAttribute("step", step);

  if (e.keyCode == 39) { //right
    // Increment the value of the range slider by the step size
    e.preventDefault();
    rangeSlider.value = parseInt(rangeSlider.value) + parseInt(step);
    console.log(rangeSlider.value ,'2');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type='range' min='0' max='84' value='0' id='range-slider' class='slider'/>
```